# "No visible @interface for 'MySwiftFile' declares the selector '****'" in iOS framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios-frameworks, objective-c-swift-bridge

I've been having trouble with using Swift in an ObjC framework in iOS. My framework has Objective-C code, which I want to call Swift code from.

I think I have created the bridging properly, I'll show below what I've done.

`MySwiftFile.swift` :

```
open class MySwiftFile: NSObject {
  var varDummy : RandomType? = nil
  open func setupDummy(param1 : RandomType1) {
    varDummy = RandomType(p: param1)
  }
}
```

`MyObjCFile.m` :

```
@class MySwiftFile;
#import "MyFramework/MyFramework-Swift.h"

@interface A : NSObject<...>
@property(atomic) MySwiftFile *mySwiftFile;

.....
@end
@implementation Aclass
......
@end

@interface B ()
....
@property(readonly, nonatomic) A *refA;
@end

@implementation B
....
- (void)methodCalledSomewhere:(RandomType1 *)type {
   ....
   refA.mySwiftFile = [[MySwiftFile alloc] init];
   [refA.mySwiftFile setupDummy: type];   <====THIS LINE PRODUCES THE ERROR
}
....
```

To sum it up, I want to init the property and call a function of a Swift object from ObjC code. Xcode seems to recognize MySwiftFile as a valid type, then how come it does not allow me to call the "setupDummy" method?

The errors are 2:

- No visible @interface for 'MySwiftFile' declares the selector 'setupDummy:'
- No visible @interface for 'MySwiftFile' declares the selector 'setupDummy'

Comment: `RandomType1` is probably inaccessible from `ObjC`.

Comment: Your `MySwiftFile` class is not exposed to the Obj-C runtime. Search for `@objc`, `@objcMembers`, ... I can't find the best answer to mark this as a duplicate, but there's a lot of them.

Comment: @user28434 Had a typo in question, just fixed it

Comment: @zrzka Didn't work adding ```@objc``` or ```@objcMembers```. Same error is produced : 

    No visible @interface for 'MySwiftFile' declares the selector 'setupDummy:'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem is that you forget to expose it to the Objective-C. Either add `@objcMembers` to expose everything ...

```swift
@objcMembers
open class MySwiftFile: NSObject {
    ...
}
```

... or just add `@objc` to your `setupDummy` function ...

```swift
@objc
open func setupDummy(param1: String) {
    ...
}
```

Second problem is about how the function name is translated to Objective-C ...

- `@objc func setupDummy(param1 : RandomType1)` -> `setupDummyWithParam1:`
- `@objc func setupDummy(_ param1: RandomType1)` -> `setupDummy:`
- `@objc(setupDummy:) func setupDummy(param1: String)` -> `setupDummy:`

... which means that adding just `@objc` wont work. You have to either change the Swift function signature or use `setupDummyWithParam1:` in your Objective-C or keep the Swift function signature & use `@objc(<name>)` to change the Objective-C selector.

Comment: Thanks, in the meantime I checked in the MyProj-Swift.h file and, in fact, setupDummyWithParam1 function was declared there. Cheers